# Cannot Resolve Symbol when importing project as well as missing Androidmanifest.xml file on Library Tree

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import a project to another computer, when I ran into this error for multiple of my import. Cannot Resolve Symbol `os`, Cannot Resolve Symbol `bluetooth`, and multiple similar error. I tried copying the project from my USB again, importing the project from `Github` through cloning, reinstall android studio, deleting .idea/library, but nothing work so far. My current assumption is that the Android Manifest.xml is not recognize on in the project tree, even though the AndroidManifest.xml file is there on my import project folder. Are there ways to resolve this problem?

[Cannot Resolve Symbol Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZS67.png)

[Android Studio Project Library Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BrXh.png)

[`AndroidManifest` in the Window Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qegrP.png)

Any help would be appreciate thanks! Let me know if any additional information are needed.

*Noted*: When creating a new project, the AndroidManifest.xml is there, but it isn't there when importing a project.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem was because I lack the necessary SDK version for my file. Now that I install all the SDK file for my project, everything work again. Thanks!